# Relearn VS learn again

Tags: meaning-in-context, learning

One of my favorite quotes is by Alvin Toffler which says:

> The illiterate of the 21st century will not be those who cannot read
>   and write, but those who cannot learn, unlearn, and relearn.

The way I understand "relearn" in the quote is to learn something new that is different from what was originally learned.

I'm wondering in general if "relearn" convey learning the same thing again, or a different thing, or it depends on the context of the sentence. Is the same thing true for "learn again"?

Comment: Essentially this is the difference between transitive _learn_, where it's the apprehension of the specific knowledge that matters -- _learn Spanish, learn piano, learn shorthand_, and intransitive _learn_, where it's the process of learning itself that's being discussed, irrespective of topic. _Learn again_ cuts off the possibility of an object, so it's clearly intransitive; _relearn_ is ambiguous between transitive and intransitive, and that's the reason one might prefer _learn again_. However, in this context, _cannot learn, unlearn, and relearn_ is clear enough in intent.

Comment: What makes you think "learn" doesn't mean "to learn something new that is different from what was originally learned"?

Comment: I definitely believe(just my experience, not proof) that people generally use "relearn" as meaning "learn another way to do something" and not "I forgot so I learned how to do it again"('learned it again').  If I were to guess why,  I would say that it comes down to the circumstances "re" is used. You typically "re-do" something when the first way didn't work ... but that isn't absolute .. you might rebuild something after a fire exactly the same way as you did the first time. Still, I think we use "re" more often than not when you're hoping for different results

Comment: We all understand it to mean 'learn entirely new things'. But it doesn't bear scrutiny. 'relearn' can only mean 'forgot it and learned the same thing again. In the context of this particular sentence, the author is making us think what he wants rather than what that word is supposed to mean literally.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Essentially this is the difference between transitive *learn*, where it's the apprehension of the specific knowledge that matters -- *learn Spanish, learn piano, learn shorthand*, and intransitive *learn*, where it's the process of learning itself that's being discussed, irrespective of topic. *Learn again* cuts off the possibility of an object, so it's clearly intransitive; *relearn* is ambiguous between transitive and intransitive, and that's the reason one might prefer *learn again*. However, in this context, *cannot learn, unlearn, and relearn* is clear enough in intent.

Comment: But one could _**learn** Spanish **again**_ or _**relearn** Spanish_.

Answer (score 0):

To learn means to acquire knowledge about something while to relearn simply means to understand the learnt information in a much better way, or in a different sense. Relearn in this context may also mean "to understand something learnt much more clearly after a particular experience before which the person who learnt it had not put the knowledge to use".