# What's the difference between the prefix "re-" and the adverb "again"

Tags: grammar, etymology, vocabulary

For example, "I will **re**read this article" and "I will read this article **again**". Are they equivalent? When should I use a hyphen after the prefix "re"?

Comment: Yes, they have the same meaning.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367134/relearn-vs-learn-again  Same question here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they mean the same thing.

We usually don't put hyphens after *re*, but when you're not sure, look up the be safe.

Comment: Answers without supporting references (linked and attributed) are rarely considered good on ELU. If it is considered that the answer is so obvious that supporting references are unnecessary, the correct procedure is to close-vote rather than write an 'answer'.

Comment: Could you explain it further, Charlie Bernstein?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving spelling aside, I would argue that "re" is mostly used in exhortations, i.e. imperatives, which does not hold for "again", as in "Please redo your homework!" vs. "I did my homework again" (because I was not happy with it).